# ERROR Mapbox error {com.xxx}[Style]: Failed to load source composite: HTTP status code 403

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I am not able to load the map and getting below error

ERROR Mapbox error {com.xxx}[Style]: Failed to load source composite: HTTP status code 403 {"level": "error", "message": "{com.xxx}[Style]: Failed to load source composite: HTTP status code 403", "tag": "Mbgl"}

Answer (score 0):

npm uninstall react-native-mapbox-gl --save &&
npm install react-native-mapbox-gl --save

Comment: is it npm i @react-native-mapbox-gl/maps or npm install react-native-mapbox-gl

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: no first you run npm i @react-native-mapbox-gl/maps

Comment: then, npm install react-native-mapbox-gl --save